# How to read chunk of file in WebAPI when file is large

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a big file, and I want to send it to Web API which will send it to Amazon. Since file is big I want to send file to Amazon in chunk wise. 
So If I have 1 GB file, I want my API to receive file in let's say 20 MB chunk so that I can send it to Amazon and then again receive 20 MB chunk. How is this doable. Below is my attempt.

```
public async Task<bool> Upload()
{
    var fileuploadPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileUploadLocation"];
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(fileuploadPath);
    var content = new StreamContent(HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferlessInputStream(true));
    // Now code below writes to a folder, but I want to make sure I read it as soon as I receive some chunk
    await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    return true;
}
```

Pseudo Code:

```
While (await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider) == 20 MB chunk)
{
  //Do something
  // Then again do something with rest of chunk and so on.
}
```

File is as large as 1 GB.

As of now entire file is getting sent by this line of code:

`await content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);`

I am lost here please help me. All I want is receive file in small chunk and process it.

P.S: I am sending file as MultiPart/Form-Data from Postman to test.

[image]

**Attempt No 2:**

```
var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
foreach (var content in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
{
   var stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
       string line = "";
       while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
           using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
           using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
           {
               sw.WriteLine(line);
               sw.Flush();
               // Do Something
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `ReadAsMultipartAsync` isn't for chunked encoded requests.

Comment: Can you kindly guide me on how to proceed. Thank You. All I want is to keep on receiving file in some chunks and keep on doing whatever I want and then get another chunk.

Comment: you will have to do that with your own stream readers.

Comment: Since I am newbie I could not follow you properly, but I have another code which loads everything in memory stream. Can you please check the `Attempt 2` in my question edits.

Answer (score 0):

No time to test this, but the ReadBlock method seems to be what you want to use.
Should look something like what I have below, but it assumes all your other code is good and you just needed some help with the buffering. This is a "blocking" read operation, but there is also a ReadBlockAsync method which returns a Task.

```
const int bufferSize= 1024;
var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
foreach (var content in filesReadToProvider.Contents)
{
    var stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        int bytesRead;
        char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
        while ((bytesRead = sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
        {
              // Do something with the first <bytesRead> of buffer and
              // not with <bufferSize> as <bytesRead> will contain the
              // number of bytes actually read by the call to ReadBlock
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I will try this now. So this code basically `1. Never uploads entire file into memory` AND  `2. It fetches 1024 data and then I can work on it, and then again it fetches some data`.

Comment: "Never" is pretty strong word as there is all sorts of networking code  below this and its buffers and if the file()s) is(are) small enough, then it(they) might all be in memory at once. I guess what I'm trying to say is that I can't guarantee you that the bytes that a StreamReader exposes to you as a stream are streaming right off the wire or a buffer of its own.

Comment: I am getting error at  `while (bytesRead = sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, bufferSize) > 0)` It says cannot `convert byte[] to char[]`

Comment: @Unbreakable - Updated the code to use a char[].  I didn't test it, I just assumed ReadBlock would work with byte[]. But now that I've read the docs, it clearly uses a char[].

Comment: I am trying your code now, just a minor adjustments, we need extra opening and closing bracket in `while condition`.

Comment: As in =>  `while ((bytesRead = sr.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188705/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-clay-ver-valen).